# How to handle row click event in jQuery grid

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery grid with data with user data. I need to handle the click on grid row for each grid row when I click I need to display other grid in the bottom of the grid.

Some thing like very similar to this:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Go to  Advanced ---> master details

Thanks

Comment: could you please post your code so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: The link http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html does no longer exist. If you can, please add a code example to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the onSelectRow is what is making the details grid load the information from the master grid.

```
   onSelectRow: function(ids) { 
            if(ids == null) {
                    ids=0; 
                    if(jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('getGridParam','records') >0 ) 
                    { 
                        jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"subgrid.php?q=1&id="+ids,page:1});
                        jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"Invoice Detail: "+ids) 
                        .trigger('reloadGrid'); 
                    }
                } else { 
                    jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"subgrid.php?q=1&id="+ids,page:1}); 
                    jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"Invoice Detail: "+ids)
                    .trigger('reloadGrid');
                } 
        }
```

Comment: The thing is on first load I need to hind the  second grid.. on clicking first row in master grid I need to disply the second gird by passing the id value.. I am passing the URL:/Friends/Names/shiva?id=AAA" is this right?
Thanks

Comment: Yes you should use a similar URL: to the one use used to load the master grid.  Also test to make sure /Friends/Names/shiva?id=AAA is actually returning data.

Comment: NO my master grid URL is differnt and My chaild grid URL is completly differnt .. Bec on click I need to pass master grid row Id to the stored procedure to display second grid result.

Comment: that why i said it should be "similar'

Comment: if it is similar both the result are same? i cant not get the second grid result based on first grid result.. 

Please correct me if I am wrong?
than s

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use it

```
$("#tablename tr").click(function(){//do what needs to be done});
```

HTH

Comment: thanks raja, 
I did the same way but I am not geting the second grid when I want to display..

Comment: Raja can you give me your Email i cant post the code here bec of security reasons? yes I will post all my code please help me out..

Comment: Inside the click event you might need to get the ID of the row. How do you get it? onSelectRow passes it as parameter. The code `var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');` does not help in this case since you react on click, not on select.

Answer (score 1):

> > Inside the click event you might need to get the ID of the row. 
> >     How do you get it?

```
$("#tblGridMain tr").click(function () {
    var tr = $(this)[0];
    var trID = tr.id;
    alert("trID=" + trID);
});
```

Comment: You may want to add a comment explaining how the code works and possibly linking to relevant documentation, rather than just giving the code.