# How to play with click event in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery

I am tring to use the click event in jqGrid, but I am having problems with it.
Here is my code below:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#gridTable").jqGrid({
                    url: '/Jqgrid/ServletPage',
                    datatype: 'xml',
                    colNames: ['Name', 'Empno', 'Age', 'Address', 'Contactno', 'Salary'],
                    colModel: [
                        {name: 'name', width: 1},
                        {name: 'empno', width: 1},
                        {name: 'age', width: 1},
                        {name: 'address', width: 1},
                        {name: 'contactno', width: 1},
                        {name: 'salary', width: 1}
                    ],
                    rowNum: 15,
                    height: 300,
                    autowidth: true,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 15],

                    loadComplete: function() {
            $("option[value=100000000]").text('All');
        },
                    pager: '#gridPager',
                    multiselect: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortname: 'empno',
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    caption: "Employee Details"
                }).navGrid("#gridPager", {edit: true, add: false, del: 'deletetext;', refreshtext: 'Refresh&nbsp;', searchtext: 'Find&nbsp;'});             

});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <table id="gridTable" ></table>
    <div id="gridPager"></div>
</body>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: For cell click event, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633524/jqgrid-how-to-write-cell-click-event) and for row click event, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595419/how-to-handle-row-click-event-in-jquery-grid)

Comment: Please edit your question so we all could read it.